# How do I trigger a tcpdump capture on Amazon ECS based on a log event?

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2, aws

I have an application that runs on Amazon ECS. Every once in a while (about once a month for a few hours), we have this issue where XML responses to our application are truncated, so an XML parse exception is logged.

I would like to have some way to monitor the logs and upon an initial exception being found in the logs, a network trace is started and runs for about 5 minutes.

What are my options?